# Generate table rows using jQuery each function

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table, each

How would I be able to generate `<tr>` s using the `jQuery` `each()` function?

See my attempt below:

HTML:

```
<html>
<table>
<tbody id = "table_tbody">
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var tr_count = 10;
var tr_var ="<tr><td><input type = 'text' name= 'name'/></td>t</tr>";
$(tr_count).each(function(){
    $(tr_var).appendTo('#table_tbody');
})
```

This returns one `<tr>`.

Answer (score 4):

Try a simple for loop.

```
//                       removed a t which should be a typo -v
var tr_var ="<tr><td><input type = 'text' name= 'name'/></td></tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < tr_count; i++ ) {
   $(tr_var).appendTo('#table_tbody');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a simple `for` loop does it. Just wondering why `each()` wouldn't work?

Comment: `$.each` iterates over a collection.. check out the jQuery documentation and the examples for better understanding. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

```
tr_count
```

is not an array.  The each function is attempting to operate on each element of the array.

Try this code

```
var tr_count = 10;
var foo = new Array();
foo.push('a');
foo.push('b');
var tr_var ="<tr><td><input type = 'text' name= 'name'/></td>t</tr>";
$(foo).each(function(){
    $(tr_var).appendTo('#table_tbody');
    alert('moo');
})​
```

I agree with Vega - go with an explicit loop